# Regex to match several strings but not specific ones

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

I'm working with Perl to search and match for strings on each line that match a criteria and would like to omit the lines that contain a specific string. 
What I mean is:
Say I'm matching the string Mouse, but I'd like to omit if the line matches X123Y. Either strings can be found anywhere on the line.

```
Stackoverflow Mouse forum.       <--Match
Stackoverflow -Mouse- forum.     <--Match
Stackoverflow X123Y forum Mouse. <--Should not Match
Stackoverflow XYZ forum Mouse.   <--Should not Match
```

I hoped this would solve it since I'm using negative lookahead but doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
(?i)(\WMouse\W|(?!(X123Y|XYZ)).*$)
```

I'm doing something fundamentally wrong I suppose, but cannot see it now.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work for you:

```
^(?=.*?Mouse)(?:(?!(?:X123|XYZ)).)*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pY0cP5/1)

Comment: Just check the regex description in the demo link for all the details about this regex. After that feel free to ask any question and I will answer it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the discard technique to keep with the content you want and discard the patterns you don't.

For example, using this regex:

```
.*X123Y.*|.*XYZ.*|(.*Mouse.*)
```

You will grab the content for the rightest pattern and discard the others..

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/aL3qG1/1)**

[image]

The idea is to use:

```
discard patt 1 | discard patt 2 | discard patt n | (grab this pattern)
```